# AWS S3 : access denied to object while "bucket block public access" is off

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am new to AWS. I am saving file to AWS from my Java Application. The file is being saved in the bucket, no problem with that. But the real problem is starting when trying to access them. Every time getting :

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>8B350BEBBDF0386B</RequestId>
<HostId>77cB7pybpshSC7TfDilGiPHvKfd91wI24iQJ8ach7jLIBuqOeB+hfDz7soLE1p0ZqrUyoRqgPCw=</HostId>
</Error>
```

I have checked the AWS setting, both my bucket and object is public. I have searched in the internet, most of the solution is talking about make ACL public, I think i already did that.

**Bucket Policy:**

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow-OAI-Access-To-Bucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::xxxxxxxbucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Allow-Public-Access-To-Bucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::xxxxxxxbucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Access-to-specific-VPCE-only",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::xxxxxxxbucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:sourceVpce": "vpce-1a2b3c4d"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

[image: account level public access.]

[image]

[image: Object Level ACL public access.]

[image: Bucket is public]

While permission has given to public, i am understanding why it is giving Access Denied Error.

Comment: There are two levels of "Block public access". Account level and bucket level. Did you disable both of them?

Comment: @Marcin are you talking about bucket policy?

Comment: The last screenshot shows "Block public access".

Comment: @Marcin yes last screen shoot : all block is off.

Comment: But is this for bucket only, or account? There are two sets of these permissions.

Comment: @Marchin bucket only.

Comment: So can you check account level "Block public access" settings?

Comment: i have updated the question, please check. are you talking about it? @Marcin

Comment: I see. Do you have any bucket policy which would deny any access?

Comment: @Marcin i have added the bucket policy, so far, i could understand, it is public.

Comment: You have `Access-to-specific-VPCE-only` which denies any access not from vpc.

Comment: @Marcin so what is the solution?

Comment: Its up to your requirements. Remove it if you want to allow public access to your objects from the internet. If not, then leave it as it is.

Comment: @Marcin thanks man, now i am getting my objects.

Comment: No problem. If you don't mind I will provide an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The bucket policy contains **explicit deny** statement, which prohibits any access to the objects from outside of a given VPC (including no access from internet):

```
        {
            "Sid": "Access-to-specific-VPCE-only",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::xxxxxxxbucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:sourceVpce": "vpce-1a2b3c4d"
                }
            }
        }
```

Thus, to make the objects publicly accessible over the internet for the website, the statement should be removed.